# ¿Columna encriptada en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, login

¡Hola!

Soy novata manejando este tipo de situaciones. Estoy trabajando con una base de datos en SQL Server, donde mi aplicación debe hacer un inicio de sesión, sin registro. Esta tabla ya fue creada y ha sido utilizada por otras aplicaciones.Sin embargo, al revisar la tabla, me he encontrado que, en la columna de password, todos los registros tienen esto: []

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagino que la columna `pass` se encuentra encriptada. ¿Sí lo está o qué significan esos []? De ser así, ¿cómo manejaría esta información? ¿Cómo puedo saber con qué algoritmo de encriptación o tipo de cifrado contiene esta columna?

Los tipos de datos de la columna son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes enviar el codigo de registro de tu app, quizas allí no estas enviando los valores, por cierto que tipo de datos utilizas para la columna de password.

Comment: Ah, es que no tengo un registro. Sólo inicio de sesión con usuarios ya registrados, donde dependiendo del rol, tienen sus privilegios. Estoy trabajando con una base de datos ya hecha y utilizada por otras aplicaciones. 

Y sí, tienes razón, No incluí eso. Ya lo agrego al post.

Comment: Si estuviese cifrado el contenido de la columna, aparecería el resultado de cifrar cada contraseña (normalmente un hash). Es necesario revisar si ese dato se está guardando en otro lugar.

Comment: Cual versión de SQL Server esta usando?. Puedes probar haciendo un trace a la BD con SQL Server Profiler y ver la consulta y los datos que están llegando a la BD al momento de iniciar sesión.